# Custom web part properties

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a custom web part, and if a user clicks on Edit web part, the properties pane in IE 11 appears and disappears, so sort of flickers.

In IE 8 it works fine.

Any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide [more details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're to get any help. (Incidentally, this seems like it belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ rather than Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 0):

This simple fix worked for me

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2459850